# Code of Computer Graphics not compiled or installation failed

Tags: c, ubuntu, opengl

I followed instruction described http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~vplab/courses/CG/opengl_start.html that is as following -

**OpenGL (GLUT) on Linux (Ubuntu) Installation**
Install the following packages from the ubuntu repository:
1. `freeglut3-dev`
2. `mesa-common-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

Check your /usr/include/GL folder to verify the installation of the openGL headers that you intend to use.
Compiling and Linking
You will have to use the `-lglut` linker option with gcc/g++ to compile a program with `glut` library.
For example, to compile the program [cube.c](http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~vplab/courses/CG/openGL/cube.c) that uses GLUT type, use

```
gcc -o cube cube.c -lglut -lGLU
```

to get the binary executable cube.

If you are not using GLUT and want to use the lower level libraries then use -lGL -lGLU also in the linker options.

But, this doesn't work for me.

```
$gcc -o cube cube.c -lglut -lGLU
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5OzQPt.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glVertex3fv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I didn't get the solution. Help me.

I want to write code in `C` and my environment is `Ubuntu 14.04`, `Intel processor`.

Comment: It might just be that you forgot to link GL;  i.e. add -lGL to the command line.

Comment: @visibleman `gcc -o cube cube.c -lglut -lGLU -IGL` same errror . see this https://pasteboard.co/H1sRJdh.png

Comment: There are multiple questions on SO about 'error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line', You should check them out, but it usually comes down to the order of linking objects.

Comment: @helal the first character in `-lGL` is a lowercase "el" (`l`), not an uppercase I (`I`).

Comment: @Banex Thank you, this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
gcc -o cube cube.c -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```